# Is __ supposed to work only with curried functions? Why is it working here?

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm trying to understand why [`__`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#__) works fine in this piece of code :

```
function editAddress (id, addressId, model) {
    return BusinessService
      .getById(id)
      .then(unless(
        () => checkUrlValue(addressId, model.id),
        rejectWithError(InvalidData.error('Invalid address data: Address id is different from request'))
      ))
      .then(pipe(
        updateModel(__, 'addresses', model, 'id', addressId),
        juxt([ always(id), identity ]),
        apply(BusinessService.editById)
      ))
      .then(pipe(
        prop('addresses'),
        find(propEq('id', addressId))
      ))
  }
```

```
function updateModel (entity, property, model, attr, id) {
  return evolve({
    [property]: pipe(
      juxt([
        findIndex(propEq(attr, id)),
        pipe(
          find(propEq(attr, id)),
          mergeLeft(model)
        ),
        identity
      ]),
      apply(update)
    )
  })(entity)
}
```

Since the function called ( updateModel ) is not curried, why does `__` still work in this case?

Comment: Interesting question.  I'd never seen this behavior, and I'm one of the founders of Ramda.  The answer from Will Jenkins explains it and my comment there expands on it.  But it's nice to know that this will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`updateModel` isn't curried, but it is returning the result of a function called `evolve` that is curried. The first call passes in:

```
{
    [property]: pipe(
      juxt([
        findIndex(propEq(attr, id)),
        pipe(
          find(propEq(attr, id)),
          mergeLeft(model)
        ),
        identity
      ]),
      apply(update)
    )
}
```

And the result of this call to evolve is then called with `entity`, which in your case will be __. Without seeing the innards of `evolve` it's not possible to understand the code any further.

Comment: Interesting, I'd never noticed this behavior.  But the explanation is exactly right.  The [`evolve` source](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/source/evolve.js) and [`_curry2` source](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/source/internal/_curry2.js), do demonstrate why.  When you pass the placeholder as the last argument to `evolve` (or any other curried function), it essentially works as a no-op, returning a function equivalent to what you would get by supplying only the earlier parameters.  But I'd never seen this in action before.

Comment: Ah, makes sense... thanks for the explanation, every day's a school day!